# Obtaining from scratch the volatility in GARCH model using R?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, modeling, garch

I'm trying to obtain the *same vector of volatility* by myself  $\sqrt{h_{t|t-1}}$ of a **Garch Model**, that I obtained "automatically" using the function *"ugarchfit"* from the package *"rugarch"*.

So after obtaining the Maximum Likelihood Estimates of $\alpha_0,\alpha_1,\beta_1$ i'm going to use the formula of the *conditional variance* $h_{t|t-1}=\alpha_0+\alpha_1y^2_{t-1}+\beta_1h_{t-1|t-2}$

so that the *conditional variance* is dependent from its past values..

the crucial point for me is that when we start this process we have $h_{1|0}$ we don't have the past value of the *conditional variance*, and the *conditional variance* obtained using the formula is different from the one obtained as output of the *"ugarchfit"* function.

here's my code:
where `Garch11_h` is the volatility obtained from *"ugarchfit"*

```
   #StackOverflow: 
rm(x)
rm(t)
rm(specGarch11)
rm(Garch11)
rm(Garch11_h)
rm(coefs)


set.seed(10)
x<-rnorm(1000,0,3)
#x<-as.data.frame(x)
#x<-t(x)
t=seq(1:length(x))
plot(t,x,type="lines")

#fitting a Garch: #ugarchfit
library(rugarch)

specGarch11 <- ugarchspec(variance.model=list(garchOrder=c(1,1)), mean.model=list(armaOrder=c(0,0),include.mean=F))
Garch11 = ugarchfit(specGarch11, data=x)
Garch11_h = sigma(Garch11)
Garch11_h<-as.data.frame(Garch11_h)
Garch11_h<-Garch11_h$V1
Garch11_h=as.numeric(Garch11_h)
x11()
plot(t,Garch11_h,type="lines")
Garch11_for = ugarchforecast(Garch11, n.ahead = 1, plot=TRUE)
#using  ugarchforecast
coefs<-coef(Garch11)
coefs
alpha0=coefs[1]
alpha0=as.numeric(alpha0)
alpha1=coefs[2]
alpha1=as.numeric(alpha1)
beta1=coefs[3]
beta1=as.numeric(beta1)

x2=x^2

#let’s try to obtain the same values for conditional variance:

h0=alpha0+alpha1*x2[1]
#this obtained using the classic formula is different from the one coming form ugarchfit


h900=alpha0+alpha1*x2[899]+beta1*Garch11_h[899] 
#this one is similar but I used the volatility from ugarchfit
```

here's the volatility that i obtain from the function "ugarchfit"
[image]

How can I do this? Thank You